# SQL Query: How to query a function/procedure body-script

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql

is there any Query syntax (predefined )in SQL Server can show a function/procedure body-script?
sth like:

```
Select * from ShowScript('MyFunctionOrProcedureName')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want

```
exec sp_helptext 'MyFunctionOrProcedureName'
```